# Does jQuery automatically decode data-* attributes?

Tags: jquery, json

I was trying to do this,

```
var worker_ids = $.parseJSON($(':selected',this).data('workers'));
```

But I kept getting back `null`. So I tried just logging

```
$(':selected',this).data('workers')
```

And it gave me back my workers as an array!

My HTML looks something like:

```
<option value="77" data-workers="[&quot;2287&quot;,&quot;2137&quot;]">COOL KIDS</option>
```

I would have expected it to come back as a string which I would have to parse.

This happens to work perfectly fine for me, but it doesn't seem like a very good design decision. What if my attribute just happened to look like JSON?

Comment: [Let see](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2): *"When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then `jQuery.parseJSON` is used to parse the string; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the `attr()` method."*

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks. I just skimmed through that page, should have ready it more carefully :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, jQuery does attempt to guess at the data type that is stored on the data attribute and converts it when using `.data` (also applies for numbers, objects, and so on).

To get the raw attribute value, use `.attr('data-workers')`

The actual operation is performed by [the internal `dataAttr` function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L329)

Answer (score 1):

For data attributes that have been created by the original HTTP response, jQuery does attempt to guess as to the intended variable type. For instance, if the original HTTP response server the attribute `data-foo="true"`, jQuery will interpret this to be the Javascript boolean `true`.

However, if you set the data attribute to a string using jQuery, jQuery will remember that you stored a string and won't attempt to guess any more.

Here's a code snippet proving what I mean:

```js
console.log(typeof $("main").data("foo"));

$("main").data("foo", "true");
console.log(typeof $("main").data("foo"));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<main data-foo="false">main</main>
```